# Access Summing Columns Wrong Result

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access-2010, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I have a Sharepoint list that contains fields for the agents to enter payment information. There is an Amount field that contains the total amount of the payment, then there are individual fields that specify how much of the Amount goes to what (Ex: Amount = $100, $50 to Late Fees, $50 to Interest).

Obviously, I want the database to add up each of these individual fields and see if it equals the Amount field. This is working fine for most of the records, however, some of the records are showing no match even though I can clearly see they match. So I added another field to show me the difference between Amount and the total of the other fields (since Access says they're different) and I'm getting some weird results.

Here's how I'm summing up each field:
[Regular Payment]+[Principle]+[Interest Only]+[Annual Fee]+[Late Fee]+[Escrow]+[CPI]+[Payoff]+[Unapplied]+[Short Payoff]

With criteria "<> [Amount]"

Lastly, all of these fields are set to Double, Standard, 2 Decimal places. Here are the results I'm getting:

```
Amount    Total     Amount_Minus_Total
515.83    982.54    -466.71   (Correct)
728.57    728.57    1.13686837721616E-13 (WTF?)
455.42    455.45    -2.99999999999727E-02 (WTF?)
1,019.30  1019.3    -1.13686837721616E-13 (WTF?)
```

Comment: I figured it out! I created a local table and just kept changing the number format until I got to "Fixed". That showed me that the total of all the fields had like 15 zeros at the end. So I was able to fix the issue by using the Format expression: Format([Regular Payment]+[Principle]+[Interest Only]+[Annual Fee]+[Late Fee]+[Escrow]+[CPI]+[Payoff]+[Unapplied]+[Short Payoff],"0.00")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format([Regular Payment]+[Principle]+[Interest Only]+[Annual Fee]+[Late Fee]+[Escrow]+[CPI]+[Payoff]+[Unapplied]+[Short Payoff],"0.00")